# Receive bluetooth connection changes after reboot

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to work with a receiver to check bluetooth connection with different devices and then log it in logcat. It works for normal cases but fail when I reboot.

Here is a normal workflow:

1. Phone on
2. Toggle bluetooth on/off
3. Reboot phone
4. Device reconnect again after reboot

I can see 2 in my logcats so normal cases works fine. But I miss 4 and don't get a single event after reboot so I don't know if we're connected again.

My manifest have this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".settings.BluetoothReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And these permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And my bluetooth reciver look like this:

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        Log.e("BluetoothReceiver", "ActionFound");
    }
    JSONObject status = new JSONObject();
    try {
        status.put("status", action);
        status.put("name", device.getName());
        status.put("address", device.getAddress());
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        status.put("time", c.getTime());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("BluetoothReceiver", status.toString());
}
```

}

Is there any easier way to do this? Everything is pretty worthless if I don't receive the first bluetooth connection event after reboot. Or do I have kickstart the receiver after the reboot in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in your `BluetoothReceiver` and  check bluetooth connection state manually.

P.S. Don't forget

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Check http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html for example

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how would I check it manually? I mean in my onReceive I have this line to get out the device:

BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

But I guess I have to change it to something else for boot completed? Do I have to get an bluetooth adapter and check connection with all devices? The reason I use receiver is because I thought you could not check connection and instead had to wait for changes.

Comment: You can use `BluetoothAdapter` class. Check examples here http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile